# Jquery onclick on ids not working for the ids returning from the ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have document.ready function for image hover.

When the image id `sign_up_close` is there in the document the hover is working. If the same id is coming from the AJAX request then the hover is not working in JQuery.

Please give a solution, I have so many functions like this to be worked on AJAX request. The AJAX request is coming with the image with the id sign_up_close.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img#sign_up_close").hover(function(){
        $("img#sign_up_close").attr("src","images/buttons/btn_type1_23_close_pp_icon_.gif");
    },function(){
        $("img#sign_up_close").attr("src","images/buttons/btn_type1_23_close_pp_icon.gif");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain your ajax request a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

If Paolo Bergantino is correct, another viable alternative is to use Jquery's LiveQuery.

Documentation can be found at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Your code would probably look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("img#sign_up_close").livequery(function() {
            $(this).hover(function() {
                $("img#sign_up_close").attr("src","images/buttons/btn_type1_23_close_pp_icon_.gif");
            }, function() { 
                $("img#sign_up_close").attr("src","images/buttons/btn_type1_23_close_pp_icon.gif");
            });
        });
});
```